# How do you list all locally installed CPAN modules?

Tags: perl, cpan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a list of installed CPAN modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115425/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-cpan-modules)

I'm beginner for perl.

Do you now How to list local installed CPAN modules?
like pear list in PHP.