# How to get the Perl package name from the path to the module file

Tags: perl

I have used [`Module::Metadata`](https://metacpan.org/module/Module::Metatdata) to get a Perl module's name from its location, but it doesn't work for some modules (like `DBIx::Class::Carp`, `DateTimePP`) where the package information is missing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Modules corresponding to Perl module information
use File::Find;
use Module::Metadata;

my @files = ();
find({
    wanted => sub {
      push @files, $File::Find::fullname
          if (defined $File::Find::fullname
        && (-f $File::Find::fullname && /\.pm$/));
    },
    follow      => 1,
    follow_skip => 2,
  },
  @INC
);

my ($file_path, $module_name, $info) = ("", "", "");
my %modules = ();

foreach $file_path (@files) {    # loop through all the perl module (.pms) found

  $info        = Module::Metadata->new_from_file($file_path);
  $module_name = $info->name;

  if (!$module_name) {
    print $file_path . "\n";
  }

  $modules{$file_path} = $module_name;
}
```

Comment: Your two questions are beginning to smell like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Perhaps explain what your real goal is?

Comment: @Miller I need to get all the Perl modules installed in the server and print their name and version accordingly.
CGI::Apache 1.02

Comment: [How do I get a list of installed CPAN modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/115425/1733163) and [How do I find out what modules are already installed on my system?](http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#How_installed_modules)

Comment: Server doesn't have perldoc installed and cpan -a doesn't list user defined packages. So the above approach works for me.

Comment: `DBIx::Class::Carp` intentially tries to hide itself from parsing.  The [src](https://metacpan.org/source/RIBASUSHI/DBIx-Class-0.08270/lib/DBIx/Class/Carp.pm) states this.  Either way, it's installed as part of `DBIx::Class`, so it's likely not needed in your inventory anyway.  As for `DateTimePP`, I can't find that module, so at minimum it's just part of `DateTime`.  Either way, I suspect you have a non-problem.  However, if you still want to pursue this, I suggest starting a third problem with your actual goal and explaining why your situation is unique and the refs I linked to won't work.

Comment: Ok, thanks Miller. I didn't know that DBIx::Class intentionally hides it. There are around 1107 modules in our server like DBIx::Class and DateTimePP where it hides/ doesn't display package names. As you suggest I will ask another question in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a (relative) perl module path to its package name is just a matter of replacing `/` with `::` and stripping the `.pm` extension.

```
my $file_path = 'Foo/Bar.pm';
$file_path =~ s#/#::#g;
$file_path =~ s#\.pm##g;
print "$file_path\n";
```

Prints:

```
Foo::Bar
```

EDIT:

If you have the fully-qualified file path, you can try something like this to strip the prefix (depending on where the module is installed) and get the relative path:

```
use Config;
my $site_lib = $Config{sitelib};
$file_path =~ s#^$site_lib/##;
```