# Shell : get function's body by it's name

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I use `zsh` (sometimes `bash`). The thing is that I have multiple `shell` scripts and I've got no idea how to code a small function for printing function code by it's name (with highlighting; I use `pygmentize -g`). Here's a small example of what I want to get:

---

```
$ getfunc "somefunc"

# from    my_little_hacks.sh
somefunc () {
    # function code
}
```

---

Is it a clean and efficient way to do it in `shell` or `awk` without using `nl` and `cat` in the best time available for shell interpreter?

It is improbable for a function to have a word `function` in it's body except for when there are nested ones there. It is also next to impossible that it has a `{` or `}` legally unpaired inside the quotes.

Comment: As an aside, using the `function` keyword is bad form -- makes your code incompatible with POSIX sh without adding any benefit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy didn't know, thanks.

Comment: On a different note -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Also, you should declare `M` local -- it's a global variable, and is changed whenever your function is called.

Comment: Also, why grep the output of `awk`, rather than asking awk to filter for lines containing the string VERSION and exit after the first match?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , I was using this answer to get it all work really clean: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30671631/4811285

Comment: Understood; my point is that that answer is... less than optimal, in terms of how it's written.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy besides, noone would use a variable of 1 letter (i j k m a b n etc.)

Comment: Single-letter variable names are used all the time. `i` in particular -- it's **the** standard name to give a counter, and it's a common convention to increment to the next letter when nesting.

Comment: It's also a little ironic to say "no-one would use a variable of 1 letter" when discussing a function you provided which uses variables whose names have only one letter. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy this is more into philosophy. I meant to say that no program should crutch on a one-letter variable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy deleted cpanlist in the post for your mercy. I dont think you should worry not :)

Comment: Doesn't that most recent edit invalidate the question entirely? Since it *is* the answer at this point? Should that be rolled back?

Comment: @EtanReisner i think it's fully illustrates what I want. Moreover, it shows the valid answer sooner than as you get to the first reply. In my personal it does not invalidate the question. You see what is asked and what is answered. Like post-editing made in many others.

Comment: You subsumed the answer into the post. That makes the answer wrong as it doesn't provide any new information. It also makes the question pointless as it now no longer even has a question to ask. The fact that the comments push the answer down is solved by the default collapsing and can be further helped if the people delete their (at this point) useless comments (something that I believe should generally be done though I don't know what the official position on that is).

Comment: @EtanReisner, k. changed for the sake of comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
declare -f funcname
```

...will retrieve the code for function `funcname` in both bash and zsh. Thus:

```
getfunc() {
  declare -f "$@" | pygmentize -l bash
}
```

Comment: damn, this is one of the moments when you realize that all you need is already written, and you just have to search..

Comment: Great idea on the pipe through pygments! I also use `declare` often enough that I had made `fn` a simple alias to `declare -f`, but will switch it to a function to enable the pipe.