# How do I re-install a cpan-autobundle

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm working with backups at the moment and instead of backing up the full disks it would be much more efficient for me just to backup the configuration of the system. So for the perl-section of things I would like to have a way to list installed modules and later reinstall those modules if needed.

I read [How do I get a list of installed CPAN modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115425/42580) about how to get the list and when reading `perldoc -l install` I found this:

> You can also use "cpan"'s "-a" switch to create an autobundle file
>   that "CPAN.pm" understands and can use to re-install every module:
>
> ```
> $ cpan -a
> ```

So I run `cpan -a`and the last two rows of the output is:

```
Wrote bundle file
    /home/ulf/.cpan/Bundle/Snapshot_2017_11_30_01.pm
```

And **yes** the file exists, but how do I use it to "re-install every module" on another host?

Note: I my have some preconceptions about this after working with [requirement-files in pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) so please bear with me.

Comment: Have you looked into the file?

Comment: Are you trying to replication the configuration of Machine_A onto Machine_B? If so, you may wish to look at a provisioning utility like chef, ansible, pupper, or salt. This can make building new boxes simple and easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open that bundle file with a text editor or `perldoc`, you'll get instructions.

> ```
> =head1 SYNOPSIS
>
> perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::Snapshot_2017_11_30_00'
> ```

Comment: Ok. I had a looked at it, but as a perl- newbie it was not as obvious to me as it should have been. Thanks!

Comment: @UlfR no problem. I just wonder _how_ that works. It seems it's going to read parse the POD, as there is no more code in there.

Comment: After moving the file to another host and trying to run it, it's not obvious where to put it either. But after putting it in my `.cpan/Bundle` directory it worked nice and clean.

Comment: You might need to use `-I.` (`perl -I. -MCPAN ...`) for `cpan` to locate the generated module (bundle). ("`-I.`" is dash, uppercase "i", period)