# How can I force the default answer to all cpan questions?

Tags: perl, cpan

Is there some `--assume-default` option to use similar to the `--assume-yes` in `apt-get` (see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/672892/).

When installing a module with `cpan` or many modules from an "autobundle" (see: [How do I re-install a cpan-autobundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573728/)) it would be convenient to be able to use the default answer always instead of watching the install and occasionally hit the return-key on my keyboard.

I would like commands like this:

```
cpan --assume-default MyNewModule
```

or:

```
ASSUME=default perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::Snapshot_2017_11_30_00'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1
```

makes compliant modules pick a default rather than asking.