# Can one just copy perl modules from one Linux machine to another?

Tags: linux, perl, centos

I have a remote CentOS server (Release 6.10) set up by someone else.  I have quite a few perl modules installed on the machine.

I have set up a local CentOS server (Release 7.7.1908).  I would like to have the EXACT same set of perl modules on my local machine.  Installing them one by one via cpan is an option but I can run into issues as some of the perl modules are older (very) versions.

I was wondering, if I can copy modules from the remote server to my local server.  Can I do that? Are there other options?

Comment: You can cross mount directory with modules to your server and add it into `@INC` variable with `PERLLIB` and/or `PERL5LIB` variables. [How to change @INC to find Perl modules in non-standard locations](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations). In this way you have to support only one modules repository (less work). Your network connection should be reliable enough or otherwise disconnect will be unpleasant surprise.

Comment: If you copy modules to server as a reminder make `backup copy` in case if you have `to retreat on previous position`. If _remote server_ is truly remote and NFS,SSH mount is not possible then copy is only option. In this case you have to find _very old modules_ copy them to your local server and install through cpan only latest modules you consider safe.

Comment: Other possible approach is use virtual environment like [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). Create VM and try recreate perl environment from remote server. In this way you will have two separate isolated perl environments on same machine.

Comment: Please see if the following [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573728/how-do-i-re-install-a-cpan-autobundle) of any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not safe to copy modules from one machine to another because things may not be set up identically.  It's best to reinstall them.

You can use the `autobundle` command in the `cpan` shell to create a dump of all the modules you have installed on the old machine.  You can then use that dump to tell the `cpan` shell on the new machine what modules to install.

Thanks to Polar Bear, here's a link to an article that explains [how to reinstall the autobundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573728/how-do-i-re-install-a-cpan-autobundle).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Was not aware about nice `autobundle` feature and how to use it before.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try that.  Could you please point me to any documentation that details how to use the commands.  I don't really have much knowledge on using cpan/perl modules.

Comment: @user2125853 - Please see my comment with instruction to your question, it is about autobundle.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look at the link.

Comment: It's better to get the auto bundle docs from the source: https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN#POPULATE-AN-INSTALLATION-WITH-LOTS-OF-MODULES

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by Andy Lester is perhaps the best way to do it.  I found a documentation [here](https://gugod.org/2010/09/migrate-to-new-perl-with-cpan-autobundle/) in addition to ones suggested.

In my case however this was not straight forward because the source server environment is very old and there were many dependencies that I will need to manually resolve.  In general if you have similar environments and clean installs, the auto bundle approach will make it easy.